# Running iPhone app in background after updating it's version

Tags: ios

Assume there is an iPhone app XXX(v0.02).I will register to this app by entering my email id and password for first time. After installation it is going to run in the background always.Next i will release an update XXX(v0.03) which installs on XXX(v0.02). What i wanted is that, XXX(v0.03) should run in background after updating it from v0.02 to v0.03, without opening it(v0.03) manually. Is there any way in ios to achieve this.

XXX(v0.02) -> XXX(application name), v0.02(version 0.02)